# Can't access hdd Raspberry pi samba share

Tags: mount, samba, file-sharing, raspberrypi

I got a raspberry pi 2 and an old hdd, so i wanted to create a samba share for this old hdd. I mounted my hdd with ntfs-3g to /media/usb which works fine.

I added this to my smb.conf file:

```
[smb]
    path = /media/usb
    available = yes
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    public = yes
    writable = yes
```

I set the permission with `sudo chmod 777 -R /media/usb` and restarted the samba service.
Next i tried to access my smb from windows, but i couldn't. It said: "no access to xxx.xxx.x.xxx/smb" and something like ask your network administrator for permission(translated from dutch). Checking my permisions with `ls -ld /media/usb` I got `drwxrwx---`

I tried other configs but none of them seemed to work. At this point I created a second share to my smb.conf with the same config, but with /home as the path. Now this share works, but my first share still doesn't, but it has the same config.

I don't understand what's wrong and I can't find a solution. Can someone help me. Has this something to do with the hdd mount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the permissions are not right. I set the permissions but the changes were lost multiple times.
I auto-mounted the hdd with the following line in my fstab file:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007 /dev/sda1 /media/NASDRIVE
```

I noticed the umask=007 which caused my problems. I changed it to 000, which I know is not save.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the samba configuration file. Since you are trying to access the share from Windows, you have to mention the workgroup as well under **[global]** settings section. This section is commented out by default.

such as below (this is just an example).

You can read more about it @https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = ubuntu
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no
============================ Share Definitions ============================== 
[Anonymous]
path = /samba/anonymous
browsable =yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```

I hope this helps!Good Luck!